# Remote Access to Laptop Microphone

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have a laptop at home which I always leave on when going to office. Since my small daughter remains home with a baby sitter, I want to be able to listen in to her while in the office.

Is there a way I can leave the laptop mic on and listen through it on my office laptop?

Answer (score 1):

Just start a Skype call? Have a RDP set up (or teamviewer log me in) in case the call gets disconnected so you can reconnect.